# How to drop a duplicate row in Pandas when the duplicate is in a different order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a Pandas data frame where I am seeing duplicate rows, although they are not technically duplicated. The values are just arranged in a different order. I am trying to figure out how to remove the duplicate row without considering the order of the data.

See below for my example

```
ID1   Name1      ID2      Name2
  1    Matt        2       John
  2    John        1       Matt
  3    Jeff        1       Matt
```

Expected Output

```
ID1    Name1      ID2     Name2
  1     Matt        2      John
  1     Matt        3      Jeff
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch the ids & names if ID1 > ID2. Then drop duplicates as usual.

```
df.loc[df.ID1 > df.ID2, df.columns] = df.loc[df.ID1 > df.ID2, df.columns[[2,3,0,1]]].values
df.drop_duplicates()
   ID1 Name1  ID2 Name2
0    1  Matt    2  John
2    1  Matt    3  Jeff
```

Answer (score 0):

This works albeit is a bit ugly: map both IDs and names into a single "uid" that will be the same when the ID1 of rowA is same as ID2 of rowB and vice versa, do likewise for name.  Then groupby that "uid" (quotes because it isnt unique, but is desired to be unique). For groups of length>1, take the first row, concat those first rows with the groups of length 1.

```
df['multID']=df.apply(lambda r:sorted([r['ID1'],r['ID2']]),axis=1)
df['multName']=df.apply(lambda r:sorted([r['Name1'],r['Name2']]),axis=1)
df['uid']=df.apply(lambda r:str([r['multName'],r['multID']]),axis=1)
g=df.groupby('uid')  
df2=pd.concat([g.filter(lambda x:len(x)>1).iloc[[0]],g.filter(lambda x:len(x)==1)],axis=0)
```

The list has to be converted to string , otherwise the filter throws 'unhashable type'.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the premise that the order of the data does not matter :

Convert dataframe to string -> move into numpy land -> **[sort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy.sort)** the array ... this will put numbers before alphabets -> return to pandas and drop duplicates

```
res = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.astype(str).to_numpy()),
                           columns = ["ID1","ID2","Name1","Name2"])
                  .drop_duplicates(["ID1","ID2"])

print(res)


   ID1  ID2 Name1   Name2
0   1   2   John    Matt
2   1   3   Jeff    Matt
```